# Multiplying matrices across tenor axis with numpy and with GPU

Tags: performance, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix `X` with shape `(F,T,M)`. I wish to multiply each `(T,M)` matrix along the `F` axis so that the answer will be of shape `(M,M,F)`. This code does the job for me but this operation repeats many times and it is very slow:

```
    for f in range(F):
        output[:,:,f] = np.matmul(X[f,:,:].T,X[f,:,:])
```

All I could find is [np.tensordot()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) function. If I understand correctly, this is not a good option for me since I need a matrix multiplication and not a dot product.

How do I implement this efficiently using numpy? Is it possible and beneficial to utilize keras\tf for this purpose?

Comment: Alongwith the posted answer, to leverage GPU, it seems we can use tf with matmul - https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `np.matmul/@ opeartor in Python 3.x` after extending dimensions -

```
np.matmul(X.swapaxes(1,2),X).swapaxes(0,2)
(X.swapaxes(1,2)@X).swapaxes(0,2)
```

Alternatively, with `np.einsum` with a direct translation off the shape variables used for the string notation -

```
np.einsum('ftm,ftn->mnf',X,X)
```

Comment: I have a `0.-7.27595761e-12j` error calculated with `np.sum(output1-output2).flatten()` when using `(X.swapaxes(1,2)@X).swapaxes(0,2)`. Should I be woried with such a small error?

Comment: @havakok Think a better way to compare is with `np.allclose()`.